# Proof by Contradiction, Real Roots

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am trying to learn how to do proofs by contradiction. The proof is,

"Prove by Contradiction that there are no positive real roots of $x^6 + 2x^3 +4x + 5$"

I understand that now I am attempting to prove that there is a positive real root of this equation, so I am able to contradict myself within the proof. I just don't even know where to start.

Comment: I am not sure why you would prove this by way of Contradiction since you can just say: "If $x$ is positive, then so is each individual term"

Comment: I am supposed to prove it by Contradiction, although there is definitely other ways

Comment: Actually I misread your question but my solution is your way of contradiction

Comment: As $f(x)=(x^3+1)^2+4(x+1)$, there can actually be no roots on $(-1,\infty)$ just by the positivity of the terms.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that there are positive real roots. These roots must be greater than zero by the definition of positive. If any root were greater than zero, each individual term would be greater than zero, so the polynomial must be greater than zero. In more mathy-language:
$$x>0\implies x^6+2x^3+4x+5>0$$
Since this is valid for all values of $x>0$, then you can argue by the Intermediate Value Theorem that it never crosses the x-axis, and, therefore, never equals zero.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$f(x) = x^6+2x^3+4x+5$$

A proof by contradiction involves supposing a statement, $A$, that you wish to disprove is true. Then you arrive at a contradiction, which means that $A$ cannot be true.

In this case our statement that we wish to disprove is "$f(x)$ has a positive root".

So we assume for contradiction, that $f(x)$ has a positive root: i.e. $\exists \alpha>0\quad\text{such that} \quad f(\alpha) =0$

So firstly, note that $f(0) = 5$

If we can show that $f(x)$ is an increasing function for $x>0$, then it would not be possible to there to be an $\alpha >0$ such that $f(\alpha) = 0$ - and so we would get our desired contradiction.

$f'(x) = 6x^5+8x^2+4>0\quad\forall x>0$ which gives us a contradiction, and hence $f(x)$ has no positive real roots.

Comment: That is a great explanation, thank you. For the sake of my understanding, could you explain in words to me what a "root" exactly is? I am having trouble understanding what it means. My knowledge of a rook is basically maxed out at (x+3)(x+4) = x^2 + 7x + 12, and the roots of this equation would be -3, and -4 correct?

Comment: @Conner Typically when we refer to the roots of a polynomial $f(x)$, we mean all the values of $x$ for which $f(x) = 0$. So when I say "$f(x)$ has a positive root", I mean there exists at least one $x>0$ for which $f(x) =0$

Comment: OHHH. I totally understand now. I really should've remembered that, I just finished Calc 2 last quarter. But this is a much different style of mathematics so I wasn't sure if it meant something slightly different maybe. Thank you so much for clearing it up.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x > 0$. Then $x^6, 2x^3, 4x > 0$ so that $x^6 + 2x^3 + 4x + 5 > 0$. This is contradiction.